# VGA Output Not Working

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, display

When I Used VGA On My New Monitor It Says Something Along The Lines Of: Cant Open Display Mode, Optimum Resolution 1366 by 768 60hz. Im Using A Raspberry pi 4 Model B 4GB Ram

Heres an image:
[image]

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: `Cant Open Display Mode` ... why don't you look at the picture you posted, instead of guessing what it says?

Comment: @jsotola Im Asking Why Its Not Working

Comment: the monitor tells you why ... it is not able to display what you are sending to it

Comment: @jsotola then how do i make it to display?

Comment: change the video output of the Raspberry Pi .... add a clear,  answerable question to your post ... right now, there is no question ... questions about the problem are not to be asked in comments